# Pandas create columns based on paragraph in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

There is a data frame where the column `reason` has a paragraph of data that looks like this:

"Alert summary as available: Provider name: ""Doe, Jane"" Provider specialty: Medical Oncology Referring provider name:  Referring provider specialty:  Account name: Cancer Clinic Masonic Cancer Clinic And Surgery Center"

I want to parse through and create separate columns for the data in this paragraph. The data frame should look like:

```
 Reason       | Provider Name| Provider Specialty| Referring provider name| Referring provider specialty| Account name| 
 "Alert Sum.."| Doe, Jane    | Medical Oncology  |                        |                   | Cancer Clinic Masonic Cancer Clinic And Surgery Center"
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: If the format is dynamic, regex would be a good choice! Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

This might get you heading in the right direction with some regex leveraging named capture groups.

**The regex**

```
rx = r'Provider name\:(?P<Provider_name>.*)' \
+ r'Provider specialty\:(?P<Provider_specialty>.*)' \
+ r'Referring provider name\:(?P<Referring_provider_name>.*)' \
+ r'Referring provider specialty\:(?P<Referring_provider_specialty>.*)' \
+ r'Account name\:(?P<Account_name>.*)'
```

**Use `str.extract()` to pull out the information**

```
df['txt'].str.extract(rx)
```

**Result**

```
   Provider_name  Provider_specialty Referring_provider_name  Referring_provider_specialty                                      Account_name
0   "Doe, Jane"    Medical Oncology                                                         Cancer Clinic Masonic Cancer Clinic And Surge...
```

You would need to clean the data a bit - like trim blanks.